# WPF DataGrid row height

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, rows

I have a datagrid in a WPF project. I've set the columns width to be have maximum limits,
and I want the data to likewise be stretched to fit in the rows. But that doesn't happen.... The contents just stays the same size and the cell is cutoff. Any ideas?

Here is the code :

```
<DockPanel>
<DataGrid x:Name="nirGrid" x:Uid="nirGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"      AlternationCount="2" SelectionMode="Single" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10,50,10,50" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" ColumnWidth="SizeToCells" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="None" HeadersVisibility="None" SelectionUnit="Cell" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" EnableRowVirtualization="False" IsReadOnly="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" MinRowHeight="0" CanUserResizeRows="True" RowHeaderWidth="0">
        <DataGrid.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Style>
        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=task_desc}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="test1" Width="SizeToCells" MaxWidth="330" >

            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=task_req_date}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="test2" Width="SizeToCells" MaxWidth="70" >

            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="delete" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="delete" ToolTip="delete" Opacity="0.8" Click="Button_Click" MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <Image Source="/exhibits;component/Images/exit1.png" Width="15" Height="15" />
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>


        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the TextBlock.  It should automatically wrap the content to your desired size.

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Column 2">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=task_req_date}" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="true" />  
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```